# Pandas. Copy multiIndex level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a DataFrame with multiIndexed columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3,-1))
df.columns = [['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], [0, 1, 0, 1]]
print(df)
```

That looks like this:

```
   A      B    
   0  1   0   1
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11
```

I want to do something like `df['C'] = df['B']` to get:

```
    A       B       C    
    0   1   0   1   0   1
0   0   1   2   3   2   3
1   6   7   8   9   8   9
2  12  13  14  15  14  15
```

I get the `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`.

I have also tried `df.loc[:, slice('C', None)] = df['B']` with no luck.

Actually my case is a little more complicated: I have one more level in the multiindex (`L0 I`) and I want to copy `df['L0 I', 'B']` to `df['L0 II', 'B']` (`L0 II` doesn't exist).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract column and create `MultiIndex` in column:

```
df1 = df['B']
df1.columns = [['C'] * len(df1.columns), df1.columns]
print (df1)
    C    
    0   1
0   2   3
1   6   7
2  10  11
```

Or select by slice and `rename` first level:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, slice('B', None)].rename(columns={'B':'C'}, level=0)
print (df1)
    C    
    0   1
0   2   3
1   6   7
2  10  11
```

And then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together:

```
df = df.join(df1)
#alternative
#df = pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1)
print (df)
   A      B       C    
   0  1   0   1   0   1
0  0  1   2   3   2   3
1  4  5   6   7   6   7
2  8  9  10  11  10  11
```

Another solution working here is use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), duplicate column with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and reshape back by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.stack().assign(C = lambda x: x['B']).unstack()
print (df1)
   A      B       C    
   0  1   0   1   0   1
0  0  1   2   3   2   3
1  4  5   6   7   6   7
2  8  9  10  11  10  11
```

Comment: somehow I haven't thought of concat. Simple. Thanks)

Comment: @avloss - Added another solution, I hope working well for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply extract a column while preserving the `MultiIndex` using `df[['B']]`.

So a very straightforward solution using this and `concat` is:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df[['B']].rename(columns={'B': 'C'})], axis=1)
print(df)
   A      B       C    
   0  1   0   1   0   1
0  0  1   2   3   2   3
1  4  5   6   7   6   7
2  8  9  10  11  10  11
```